# Controlling Dynamixel MX24T, MX64T servo wirelessly using Arduino Mega?

Tags: serial, servo

I am planning to control multiple Dynamixel servos (MX28T or MX-64T) wirelessly using an Arduino Mega. Since this servo uses serial communication, I need an additional serial port to interface with XBee module. Although it seems to be very common application controlling these servos wirelessly based on Arduino, I could't find any of them in web. I found the two very well constructed libraries.

1. https://code.google.com/p/slide-33/downloads/list. This library is for MX28T servo, which is the same servo I am trying to use, but it uses UNO;therefore, I cannot interface with XBee.
2. [The Arduino/Dynamixel Resource Page...](http://www.pablogindel.com/informacion/the-arduinodynamixel-resource-page/) This library uses UART1 (serial1) to interface with servo (AX-12) motors. Therefore, I can connect XBee module to UART0. But, the problem is that this library is outdated and not compatible with MX64-T servo anymore.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any one who has experience in controlling Dynamixel MX24T, MX64T servo series using XBee module simultaneously? If you have experience, please share with me.
2. Is it possible for Arduino Mega can interface with Xbee module using Serial1 (i.e., RX18 TX19)? If it can, I might be able to use the library1 without any modification.

Answer (score 1):

I know, Although it is not ZigBee, ROBOTIS Arduino Shield(https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/interface/dynamixel_shield/) can use BLE module (BT-410). My recommendation is Arduino compatible OpenCM 9.04(https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/controller/opencm904/).

Arobotix-M(https://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/arbotix-robot-controller.aspx), you can use ZigBee.